# Draggable items that can transfer between arrays using React Sortable and React.JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently stuck with an issue I've yet to solve. Im doing an application using React.JS. Currently i have a component called SortableList which i pass data to with a prop called data, this is what the structure looks like:

```
(Array) Students
  (Object) Name: 'Not Assigned', Items: (Array) - This is an array containing multiple objects and each of them contains a user.
  (Object) Name: 'Assigned', Items: (Array) - Empty
```

In the SortableList component i iterate the data prop sent with the data above, it outputs two lists and one of them is empty (The assigned) and the other is filled with users (The not assigned one). I can re-arrange in the not assigned one and it spits out the updated object for each change that is happening. The main problem for me is telling ReactSortable that it can move an user object to the other list array in the object "Assigned".

This is what my iteration looks like inside the SortableList component:

```
return(
  this.props.data.map( (list, i) => {
    return (<div style={{'marginBottom': '1em'}}><h3>{list.name}</h3><div className="list-container">
      { list.items.map( (item, i) => {
        return (
          <SortableListItem
            key={i}
            updateState={this.updateState}
            items={list.items}
            draggingIndex={this.state.draggingIndex}
            sortId={i}
            outline="list"
            childProps={childProps} className="list-item">
            {item.firstName} {item.lastName}
          </SortableListItem>
        );
      }) }
    <div style={{'clear': 'both', 'width': '100%'}}></div>
    </div></div>);
  })
);
```

In this example i named each user item, would probably be easier to understand if it was named user, since that's what it is.

I hope this question makes any sense and that I have provided sufficient information. Thanks for the help, in advance.

Comment: On what action do you want to move the item from not assigned to assigned list, if that's what your requirement is?

Comment: When the item is dragged onto the container for assigned list

Comment: `SortableList` is not a good solution for the problem you mentioned. It is actually used to sort items within a particular list and listen to those actions, such as reordering the list as the user requires. If you want to drag and drop element rows and listen that event on a div, you should try `react-dnd` (https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd)

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the help. Will give react-dnd a go and see if it handles my needs better.

Comment: Sure. No worries.

Answer (score 0):

I got the functionality I wanted with react-dnd and react-dnd-touch-backend, react-dnd is a much more powerful package but if you're looking for a simple way to re-arrange one list react sortable is a good choice.

Many thanks to @Prabhjot Rai for the suggestion.